# how to escape comma in Salesforce lightning URL

Tags: lightning, urlhacking

I have to pass a percentage value with 2 decimal places through URL hacking in lightning, for French locale the decimal point is replaced with comma, now when I send the value containing comma, salesforce is not able to parse the URL and it is considering the later part of decimal as a field that is passed in URL.

```
if(UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() == 'Theme4d'){
        url = '/lightning/o/Contract/new?defaultFieldValues=AccountId=' + accId;
        url = url + ',' + 'ZTS_EU_Related_Contract_Template__c' + '=' + contractTemplateDetail.Id;
        if(contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_Discount_Type__c == 'Fixed Discount'){
            url = url + ',' + 'ZTS_EU_Discount__c' + '=' + discountValueFinal;
        }
        
        if(contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_CTBusiness_Unit__c != null){
            url = url + ',' + 'ZTS_EU_BusinessUnit__c' + '=' + contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_CTBusiness_Unit__c;
        }
        
        url = url  + ',' + 'ZTS_EU_Type__c' + '=' + contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_Type__c;
        url = url + ',' + 'ZTS_EU_Discount_Type__c' + '=' + contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_Discount_Type__c;
        url = url + ',' + 'ZTS_EU_Fiscal_Year__c' + '=' + contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_Fiscal_Year__c;
        url = url + ',' + 'ZTS_EU_End_Date__c' + '=' + date.parse(endDateString);
        url = url + ',' + 'StartDate' + '=' + date.parse(startDateString);
    }
```

Now the variable "discountValueFinal" contains the comma for french locale, the URL is created as -

```
/lightning/o/Contract/new?defaultFieldValues=AccountId=001F000001IgAPH,ZTS_EU_Related_Contract_Template__c=a1V3k000005AKO7EAO,ZTS_EU_Discount__c=1,00,ZTS_EU_BusinessUnit__c=a0oF000000DYx9UIAT,ZTS_EU_Type__c=Annexe,ZTS_EU_Discount_Type__c=Fixed Discount,ZTS_EU_Fiscal_Year__c=2020,ZTS_EU_End_Date__c=2020-10-31 00:00:00,StartDate=2020-10-01 00:00:00
```

Here you can see ",00" is present inside it which is creating problem.

```
No access to field 00. Either the field was removed from the entity or access to this field was removed
```

Please help to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `PageReference` class to encode URL parameters on your behalf safely rather than attempting to handle it manually.

Here is the equivalent of your code using this pattern.

```
if (UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() == 'Theme4d') {
     
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/lightning/o/Contract/new');

    Map<String, String> params = pr.getParameters();
    params.put('AccountId', accId);
    params.put('ZTS_EU_Related_Contract_Template__c', contractTemplateDetail.Id);
    params.put('ZTS_EU_Type__c', contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_Type__c);
    params.put('ZTS_EU_Discount_Type__c', contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_Discount_Type__c);
    params.put('ZTS_EU_Fiscal_Year__c', contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_Fiscal_Year__c);
    params.put('ZTS_EU_End_Date__c', date.parse(endDateString));
    params.put('StartDate', date.parse(startDateString));

    if (contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_Discount_Type__c == 'Fixed Discount') {
        params.put('ZTS_EU_Discount__c', discountValueFinal);
    }   
    
    if (contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_CTBusiness_Unit__c != null) {
        params.put('ZTS_EU_BusinessUnit__c', contractTemplateDetail.ZTS_EU_CTBusiness_Unit__c);
    }

    url = pr.getUrl(); // let the pagereference class urlencode the parameters for you

    system.debug(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include commas in the defaultfieldvalues in a lightning URL by replacing them with `%2c`.